# Encountered an issue while trying to run docker-compose.yml in IntelliJ IDEA, where it cannot locate the specified file

Tags: docker, intellij-idea, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm encountering a problem where everything works fine when I execute the Dockerfile using IDEA, but I'm facing an issue when I try to execute the docker-compose.yml file. It's complaining that it can't locate files under the 'target' directory.I have tried using Windows Docker and everything is working fine. How can I resolve this problem? Below is a portion of the code. Thank you.

Operating environment 
IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.1 
CentOS 7 
Docker version 24.0.5 
Docker Compose version v2.20.3

Dockerfile

```
FROM java:openjdk-8u111-jre-alpine
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /home
COPY ./target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home
CMD ["java", "-jar", "test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  webapp-test:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    working_dir: /home
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

[Directory Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGh8w.png) 
[Exception information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UB7Wu.png)

Comment: try to give full path `C:\Users\14548...` not only `./target/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`

Comment: @AZxBB Yes, that's a solution. But why does everything work when executing the Dockerfile?

Comment: As I suppose you are making docker image from IDE. IDE knows full path and no need to  mention

Comment: @ShukurilloBaikhanov Docker Compose is unable to locate the 'target' directory. There are no issues when building independently using the Dockerfile. Strangely, when I moved 'test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar' to the 'src' directory and used './src/test-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /home', Docker Compose worked fine. I'm having trouble understanding how it functions.